# Showing blocks basing on content type

Tags: blocks, nodes

Can anyone provide a snippet code that is applicable for Drupal 6?

Answer (score 1):

If used from inside the Drupal 6 Block UI Admin Page use php area:

```
$whereami=menu_get_object();
if (isset($whereami->type) && $whereami->type=='TYPEYOUARELOOKINGFOR') {
  return TRUE;
} else {
  return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: And this is for drupal 6? :D

Answer (score 0):

With the following code snippet, your block will be visible, if you add, edit or view a node of a specific content type:

```
<?php 

    $type = 'my-content-type';

    if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
      $node = node_load(arg(1));
        if ($node->type == $type) {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }

    if (arg(2) == $type) {
        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;

?>
```